# Event happens between read and clear operations, so, last data will lose

Tags: c#, algorithm, events, event-handling

I want to explain my question by samples, because it is algorithmic issue.

Assume that, a tool and client (2 sides) use 1 `.txt` file. When tool's event happens, it opens `.txt` file and write log there. And for every 10 seconds client opens that file and check, if there are any logs there, it delete them.

I think that, when client opens file for 10 seconds, file can be used by tool (event happens) or reverse, when tool's event happens file can be used by client. On this cases data will lose?

Assume that Client use `SomeTool` and tool has an event named `SomeEvent`. So, when I start to use that tool, `SomeEvent` can happen in any time.

```
public class Client {
    private readonly SomeTool _someTool;

    public Client ()
    {
     //...
     _someTool.eventSomeThing += new SomeThingEventHandler(client_evSomeThing);
    }

    private void client_evSomeThing(object sender, Something data)
    {
     // event happens and 
     // this tool open file, write log there.
    }
}
```

Client start to work.

```
Client _client = new Client();
```

And for every 10 seconds, I do this operation: Read file and clear it.

```
 Line1.      var logInFile = _client.ReadLinesFromFile("filePath");
 Line2.      File.WriteAllText("filePath", String.Empty);
```

My question is that, what will happen if tool's event will start to work between **Line1.** and **Line2.** ? Will I lose last data? Because event can happen after I read and I will clear that data witout read it.

Same idea. I have same algorithmic problem with property, not file.

```
  var iReadProperty = _client.SomeProperty;

  //Can event happen here? If yes, Event will give it some value.
  //i will delete it and lose last value of SomeProperty. How can I solve this issue?

  _client.SomeProperty = null; // i read it, and delete it.

  // Now I think iReadProperty is last value, but it is not exact. Last value is deleted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LockFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get an exclusive lock both in the client and the tool. If the file is already locked the calling function will be suspended until the lock is released.

For the property is better to use a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): you call WaitForSingleObject before reading or writing the property and then release the lock with ReleaseMutex.

Comment: I love making calls to the native Windows API's for simple tasks...I'm sure Jhoon Bey will love it too :)

Comment: @Leo If client and server are 2 completely different processes I don't know hot to synchronise them in Windows without using WIN API

Comment: You can put a Write Lock on the file and check whether the file is locked or not before wirting (or reading) the file using managed code